# What is the grammatical structure of “I woke up tired”?

Tags: syntax, parsing, adjective-order

1. I woke up tired.
2. I grew up rich.

Can someone explain the position and functions of the adjectives tired, rich, poor in these sentences? Aren't adjectives supposed to always precede or succeed a noun and affect the meaning of it, not verbs?

Answer (score 2):

The adjectives following the phrasal verbs (linking verbs, specifically) in your two sentences are what are called  **subject complement** in grammar: they describe the *subject.*

The definition of an adjective isn't confined to a POS modifying a noun phrase. Adjectives come in various avatars. When an adjective describes the *object* of a sentence, it is called an *object complement.* *vain*, an adjective for example, is the *object complement* of the sentence *Success made him vain*, where it describes the *object* of the sentence.

Comment: to wake up is an active verb.

Comment: @Lambie But Macmillan dictionary doesn't agree with you https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wake-up%23:~:text%3DWAKE%2520UP%2520(phrasal%2520verb)%2520definition%2520and%2520synonyms%2520%257C%2520Macmillan%2520Dictionary&ved=2ahUKEwi1vPjYhY3wAhWj63MBHfz0BsAQFjABegQIAxAF&usg=AOvVaw0XiNWK7ZbxUHNiLuvKENrY

Comment: "Tired" and "rich" are optional depictives, and hence predicative adjuncts, not complements

Comment: @BillJ: In the heart of hearts I agree with most of your views as to why Pullum etal. make more sense than trad stuff. For example, I found this on some linguistics SE Q and this made me realise instantly that you're right: "_The property that adjectives assign is not an intrinsic characteristic of the noun, but rather its applicability is transient. Adjectives that assign intrinsic properties cannot occur in this use, e.g._

 *John died interesting.* But it's hard to shun the old terminology most of us have been weaned on. It does suffice sometimes, but sometimes it appears outright absurd.

Answer (score 0):

The verbs in your examples are acting as copular verbs, connecting the subjects to adjectives that are called subject complements.

The are analogous to simpler examples:

He is healthy.
They are ready.
The building seems beautiful.

In all these examples, an adjective is coupled to the subject by a verb acting as a copula. So, adjectives change the meaning of a noun, but they don't always have to be adjacent to them.

Comment: "Tired" and "rich" are optional depictives, and hence predicative adjuncts, not complements.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. But if I'm not mistaken, *The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (CGEL)* calls these predicative adjuncts. Other examples are such as:

> They look even more fantastic *naked*
>
> They served us our coffee *black*

They are not predicative complements. A predicative complement is generally obligatory and has to be licensed by a verb, eg:

> He talked himself *hoarse*

A predicative adjunct is optional and depictive.

Comment: Not quite: "hoarse" is obligatory and thus PC, not an adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I use that as an example of PC.

Comment: Yes, it's a resultative PC.